# Am using notepad to write javascript but when I put it into chrome it just shows the base code

Tags: javascript

I am watching a tutorial online and just copied what the guy put online.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Random </title>
  <lik rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
</div>
<script
alert(hello);

</script


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well the script is not valid.Your script tags are not well formed.<script></script> and you have no variable hello

Comment: If that's what he put in his tutorial you should stop watching and find something different.

Answer (score 1):

`<script` should be `<script>` and `</script` should be `</script>`

And `hello` should be **String** `"hello"` or it will be undefined.

so basically

```
<script>
alert("hello");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please correct your HTML markup. Tags need to be wrapped by angle brackets from both sides like: `<script>`.
2. If you use some variable in JavaScript, please define it first, `hello` in this example. Like this: `var hello = "some value here";` or use it literal like this: `alert("hello")`
3. Please check if the file is saved correctly, with `.html` or `.htm` extension.
4. To avoid spelling errors you can use *Sublime Editor 3*, *Notepad++*, some other more feature rich text editor or complex IDE like *Eclipse*, *Netbeans*, *Atom*, etc.
5. Tag `<lik ... />` should be `<link ... />`. Letter "n" is missing. Also if you reference the file make sure it is available.

You can check working example here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Random </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <script>
    var hello = "hello world!"
    alert(hello);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script tags are malformed, they need to be closed:

```
<script>
alert("hello");
</script>
```

Comment: I guess I would assume that the variable had been set at some point. It wouldn't be an error exactly, just print out 'undefined'.

Answer (score -1):

did you make sure that your file type is .html?
if you use notepad, the default file type is .txt